# useEffect renders components without a dependency array

Tags: reactjs

In my example I faced that without the dependency array how come the timer keeps on updating.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    };
  }, []);


  return (
<div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I found that even thought I remove the cleanup function in the return in the `useEffect` the timer keep on going, so what's the use of the cleanup function and how come it renders without actually passing the array, my doubt is who is saying the `useEffect` to re-render and update the state of count by +1.

Comment: I see your code is working, although there might be a memory leak. Anyway, what do you really want to achieve, if not that `count` increases by 1 every second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without the dependency array how come the timer keeps on updating.

The timer gets updated because it's `value` is stored outside the `useEffect` so it's not getting reset with every `useEffect` call. The downside is that the `useEffect` will be now called every `1000ms` and a new *interval* instance will be created and cleared (which is not quite good from the performance and memory management perspective).

> even thought I remove the cleanup function ie the return in the useEffect the timer keep on going

If you remove the cleanup function, the timer will still get the `value` updated, but if you will *unmount* the component, the `interval` will still keep going, which is called *memory leak* (it uses the browser's memory even if it's not needed at all).

---

More info about *memory leak*: https://dev.to/jeremiahjacinth13/memory-leaks-how-to-avoid-them-in-a-react-app-1g5e

Comment: ok so basically the timer should only update from 0 to 1 (as useEffect will get called the as the app gets its initial render), but it keeps on incrementing due to the memory leak. Am I correct? or is it because of the function setInterval() that calls the useEffect every second?

Comment: @Priyam The memory leak happens only if you unmount the component that uses interval. If you don't, the timer will work even without the dependency array because it gets re-initialized with every re-render (every `setCount` causes a re-render).

Comment: O thanks, I thought the re-render of the component only happens in useEffect and also only if it is made to run stating some variable in its dependency array. But thanks i got the concept.